# How to render white space and paragraphs in varables when storage in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that enables members on a site to message each other; the message is stored in a MySQL database. When a member sends a message to another member, I want to keep the  natural flow of the message, i.e with white space and paragraphs etc. However, these are removed when the message is stored in MySQL.

I am aware that there is a PHP function that allows this to happen, but I am not sure what it is. Below is an example of what I am referring to. I hope it offers better insight to what I mean.

**An example message:**

```
dear Tom 
thank you for contacting me. 
the details are here.
```

The above example has 3 seperate lines with white space. However, it  is rendered as follows in the MySQL table:

```
dear Tom thank you for contacting me.   my details are below.
```

Can somebody please tell me what the PHP function is that will allow it be be rendered naturally but still escape unwanted values.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php

Comment: hi Fabian. the function works to insert into mysql. but when i tried to render it, i get the </br> in my html. do you have any idea how i can render without the line break tag showing

Comment: Are you sure the GET request still contains the whitespaces? It is likely that the browser removed them before sending the HTML form, check the wrap of your textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php) is what you're looking for.

But don't use it before inserting to the database. Use it in the presentation layer.

The database will contain the message as entered by the user. Then you can choose how to display it later.

With `<br>` tags:

```
<p class="message"><?=nl2br($message)?></p>
```

Or perhaps in the future you might want to use a `<pre>` tag instead:

```
<pre><?=$message?></pre>
```

Note the absence of the call to `nl2br` in the `pre`. I know you don't wish to display it in a `pre` tag for now, I'm just using it to demonstrate the point.

Comment: hello Bcmcfc. thank you so much for your help. once last question. how will i render links. i mean, if a user writes a link. how can i then rendered that link after its been produced from the mysql database

Comment: Bit of a can of worms there. You need to only allow a subset of HTML. Sure they could enter a link but they could also enter something else that wrecks your page. Needs to be a new question.